# SQL column collation change

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, collation

I would like to change a column collation to some Polish collation and be able to view Polish characters properly. All three, original column, original table and original database, use SQL_Scandinavian_CP850_CS_AS.

For column collation change I tried:

```
SELECT CAST([ColumnName] AS nvarchar(50)) COLLATE Polish_CI_AS FROM t1
```

These 3 example letters appear in Scandinavian table:

```
SELECT 'ØùÒ' COLLATE Polish_CI_AS
```

Should return in results `łŚń`. Instead it shows 'OuO'.

Comment: What is the datatype of the columns, varchar or nvarchar?

Comment: In original db it is varchar.

Comment: Try "SELECT N'ØùÒ' COLLATE Polish_CI_AS", it may help. (I don't know SQL Server very well.) But does collation matter as long as you only view values? (It matters when comparing/sorting values.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately SQL Server does not support OEM code page 852 which is what you need to convert code page 850 data into if you want to convert 'ØùÒ' to 'łŚń'. You can change the collation of data without SQL Server doing character mapping by CASTing through varbinary, but this only works with supported collations.

An alternative approach might be to create a user-defined function that takes a string and maps characters one-at-a-time, so Ø maps to ł etc. Fiddly to do, there are (up to) 127 characters to map, but not difficult.